# Getting current window username

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have following function that will get the current windows logged in.
Problem is I have to enable unsafe activeX control to that. 
I was wondering if there was some better solution available. I have seen other older posts each one has its limitations. Wondering what is new in 2014 that might be better way to go.

```
function GetCurrentUsername() {
        var objNet = new ActiveXObject("WScript.NetWork");
        var strUserName = objNet.UserName;
        var strDomain = objNet.UserDomain;
        alert(strUserName);
    };
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need your user's local login user name? This seems like a significant privacy breach, and is unlikely to be supported anywhere.

Comment: In my application internal to the organization people post information and need to pick up there username to show who posted it.

Comment: If your application is internal, you could set a group policy to add the site (hosting the above snippet) to the trusted sites list, allowing unsigned ActiveX.

Comment: I think that sounds good. But this would limit them to IE browsers only? Cause cant see activeX plugin for firefox. So was wondering if there is something better solution using javascript that can be used across browswers.

Comment: Generally speaking browsers are pretty limited in what they have access to, ActiveX is a plugin architecture for IE which allows a lot more in terms of access to Windows systems.  The only way I can really see this working is if you were to create a socket server that gets installed as a service on all the computers in the company that could be communicated with via javascript web-sockets (or a full http server of some sort)

Comment: http://ldapjs.org/ since AD supports LDAP I believe this may work to help you write a component that would run on the end users computers, the only problem with this I think will be distribution.